# Problems with onclick link events on safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, safari

I'm having problems with navitation on safari using nodejs with expressjs and javascript. I have links with a function on its onclick event like this one (simplified version):

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToPublicView('/home/main')">
```

I have this method defined on javascript (is important to know that this is a reduced example. Is necesary to have the onclick event with a function for doing more stuff rather than navigation):

```
function goToPublicView(viewUrl) {
    window.location = window.location.origin + viewUrl;
}
```

When the link is clicked on chrome or firefox it works perfectly, but on safary this method doesn't seems to work (no error messages that I could see).

If I write the method on console it works

```
goToPublicView('/home/main');
```

I don't understand what could be the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure `window.location.origin` contains what you expect? If you do `console.log(window.location.origin + viewUrl);` do you see the expected URL?

Comment: Yes, it contains the same in chrome , firefox and firefox, but good point.

Comment: Can't really help you here without the full HTML. Are you importing your JavaScript correctly? Can it resolve `/home/main`? Please update with more complete code example.

Comment: thanks, it was difficult to reproduce the error, but reinstalling safari it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be any problem with browser. I reinstalled safari and it works fine.